# Create dataframe column with cosine distance between each row and a vector

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe :

```
file_1  0.797647  ...  0.000000
file_2  0.000000  ...  0.000000
file_3  0.000000  ...  0.000000
```

Let's call it `df`.
Each row has an index (`file_x`) and 4096 columns (without name).

I also have a vector (called `test_file`) of size 4096 for which I want to compute cosine similarity with each and every row in `df`.
The underlying idea is to append the result in a new column that I could sort to get the best 5 results.

Until now, I was using `iterrows()` to perform the `cosine_similarity` measure between my vector and each row.

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cos_sim = cosine_similarity(row.values.reshape(1, -1), test_file)
```

But for performance issues, I'd like to use pandas or numpy methods that are more adapted to matrix computation.

I was looking at `.apply()` or `.assign()` method using lambda function, but I don't know how to proceed (all examples are using named columns which I don't have).

I would like to do something like

```py
df.assign(cos_sim = cosine_similarity(df[:], test_file))
```

But how do I get the current row to operate the similarity on ?

I also investigated `cdist` from scipy library using something like `df["cos_dist"] = cdist(np.stack(df.vector), test_file, metric="cosine")`, but I don't know how to keep the index information from my original dataframe.

Comment: You can use apply on row with `axis=1` argument

Comment: Yes, but how do you define the function to be applied ? I need to use all columns in each row as a vector for comparison with my `test_file` vector.

Comment: try something like `lambda row: cosine_similarity(row.values.reshape(1, -1), test_file)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `apply`, just let sklearn do the calculation on the whole array:

```
df['cos_sim'] = cosine_similarity(df, test_file).reshape(-1)
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

n,m = 4,3
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(m,n), index=['file_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,m+1)])
test_file = np.random.randn(1,n)

df['cos_sim'] = cosine_similarity(df, test_file).reshape(-1)
print(df)

#               0         1         2         3   cos_sim
#file_1  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  0.890653
#file_2  1.867558 -0.977278  0.950088 -0.151357  0.760393
#file_3 -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274  0.360205
```